# vba error 424 with Collection of Objects

Tags: vba, object, collections

I am working on building and referencing a collection of custom Objects.  The class is called CProject, and have two properties of Name and RefNum.

The code to create and reference looks like this:

```
Dim Projects As Collection

Sub BuildProjects()
      Dim i As Integer
      Set Projects = New Collection

  For Each c In Worksheets("Active Projects").Range("A4:A750").Cells
    If IsEmpty(c) Then

        'Do some stuff

    Else
        If Projects.Count > 0 Then
           For i = 1 To Projects.Count
                If c.Value = Projects.Item(i).Name Then '<---Error Occurs Here

                    'Do some Duplicate Management Stuff

                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

When I run this code I get an error 424: Object Required.  I believe I am providing a qualified Object identifier.  Anyone out there see where I have made a mistake?

Comment: have you tried debugging using the Locals window to examine the contents of the Projects Collection?

Comment: Assuming the item you are adding is the project name then try: `If c.Value = Projects(i) Then`

Comment: How are you populating your Collection with the custom objects? At the start of your Sub you reset the Collection but where do you then add objects to it?

Answer (score 0):

The Collection items are Variant types, so you can change with this:

```
Dim Projects As Collection

Sub BuildProjects()
      Dim i As Integer
      dim var_item as variant
      dim aCProject as CProject

      Set Projects = New Collection

  For Each c In Worksheets("Active Projects").Range("A4:A750").Cells
    If IsEmpty(c) Then

        'Do some stuff

    Else
        For Each var_item in Projects
            set aCProject = var_item
            If c.Value = aCProject.Name Then 

                'Do some Duplicate Management Stuff

            End If
        Next 
    End If
Next
End Sub
```